# SQOOP --query with SCHEMA in SQL Server

Tags: hive, cloudera, sqoop, parquet

I'm trying to use the `--query` option in sqoop to import data from SQL Server. My concern is, how can we declare which schema to use with --query in SQL Server.

My script:

```
sqoop \
--options-file sqoop/aw_mssql.cfg \
--query "select BusinessEntityId, LoginID, cast(OrganizationNode as string) from Employee where \$CONDITIONS" \
--hive-table employees \
--hive-database mssql \
-- --schema=HumanResources
```

Still produces an error

> Invalid object name 'Employee'

Also tried

```
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.17;database=AdventureWorks;schema=HumanResources"
```

but that also failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below code:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.17;database=AdventureWorks \
--username "Your User" \
--password "Your Password" \
--driver  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \
--verbose  \
--query "select BusinessEntityId, LoginID, cast(OrganizationNode as string) from HumanResources.Employee where \$CONDITIONS" \
--split-by "EmpID" \ 
--where " EmpID='Employee ID' " \
-m 1  \
--target-dir /user/cloudera/ingest/raw/Employee\
--fields-terminated-by "," \
--hive-import \
--create-hive-table \
--hive-table mssql.employees \
```

1. `hive-import` – Import table into Hive (Uses Hive’s default delimiters
   if none are set.)
2. `create-hive-table` – It will create new HIBE table. `Note:` Job
   will be failed if a Hive table already exists. It works in this
   case.
3. `hive-table` – Specifies `<db_name>.<table_name>`.

Comment: Hi, my concern is the source table EMPLOYEE is under the schema HumanResources, under AdventureWorks database. How can i declare the script to use the HumanResources schema as a source.Thanks

Comment: Then in --query parameter try to use `HumanResources.Employee`

Comment: Oops! my bad! HumanResources.Employee was the solution. Just didn't realize Binary is not supported in Parquet. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please try this and let me know the error: `sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.17;username=myuser;password=mypassword;database=AdventureWorks' --table HumanResources.Employee --target-dir /data/Employee --split-by EmployeeID`

Answer (score 0):

The sqoop command you are using is missing a few things. 1st of all you need to specify that this is an sqoop import job. apart from that your query needs to have a connection string. Moreover i dont know what argments you are passing inside the options file so if you had posted the details it would have been easier and i am not sure about the `-- --schema=HumanResources` thing as i haven't seen it. A correct working sqoop example query is :

```
sqoop import --connect <connection string> --username <username> --password <password> --query <query> --hive-import --target-table <table_name> -m <no_if_mappers
```

Moreover keep this in mind while using `--query` tool you need not specify the `--table`  tool, otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: The issue is, my source table is under the schema HumanResources, not the default dbo schema. Basically it's like AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Employee. How can i set the script to query under the HumanResources schema? Thanks

Comment: You should try just --query 'SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee WHERE $CONDITIONS'

Answer (score 0):

`-schema` can work in conjunction with `-table`, but not with `-query`. Think what would that mean, it would require to parse the text of the query and replace every unqualified table reference with a two-part name, but not table references that are already two-part, three-part or four-part names. And match **exactly** the syntax rules of the back end (SQL Server in this case). It's just not feasible.

Specify the schema explicitly in the query:

```
select BusinessEntityId, LoginID, cast(OrganizationNode as string)
from HumanResources.Employee 
where ...
```

Comment: tried HumanResources.Employee but still failed. ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Type string is not a defined system type.

Comment: Yes, please use valid SQL Server syntax. Refer to the [Transact-SQL reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference). There is no such type as `string` in T-SQL to CAST to.

Comment: Oops! my bad! HumanResources.Employee was the solution. Just didn't realize Binary is not supported in Parquet. Thanks a lot!